# Saving Multiple Data into Database from Different Controllers - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am have two different controllers, user and company . I want to save the data from user controller and company controller at the same time. Is it a good practice to combine the store method from company controller in the user controller?

**User Controller**

```
  $user = new User(array(
            'name'  => $request->get('name'),
             ));

            $user->save();

    $company = new Company(array(
            'name'  => $request->get('name'),
             ));

            $company->save();
```

Comment: Is User & Company related to each other?

Comment: @x3ns yes, one user to one company

Comment: Techincally you can, but I wouldn't, since it violates the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @pseudoanime, please how would you have had your way around it then?

Comment: Are you familiar with the repository pattern? The gist of it is that everything that interacts with the repository (db) is separated out into their own concerns, like how user & company has it's own model, they also have corresponding repositories. and all the CRUD operations are performed within the repositories. So, in the controller (should be the services layer if your application is large), you call both the repositories' create methods and pass in the request parameters as arguments.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is a wider design level principle. If you just want to get the code working, I'd go with any of the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the relationship set up correctly you can:

```
$user = \App\User::create([
  "name" => $request->name,
  "company_id" => \App\Company::create([
    "name" => $request->name
  ])->id
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `company_id` in your `users` table, and inside your User model:

```
public function company() {
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

It would be fine to save both the company & user in the UserController. The best approach would be to use [Eloquent Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) and wrapping both saves in a transaction.

```
\DB::transaction(function() {
    $user->save();
    $user->company()->save($company);
});
```

Or another approach:

```
$user->setRelation('company', $company)->push()
```

The magic of `push()` will save the User & Company in one-go.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user and the company first

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->save();
$company = new Company();
$company->name = $request->name;
$company->save();
```

then, look at your relation

> if one user can have one company(in company's table has user_id)

```
$user->company()->save($company);
or
$company->user()->associate($user);
```

> if one company can have one user(in user's table has company_id)

```
$company->user()->save($user);
or
$user->company()->associate($company);
```